# Unique lines of very huge text file in python

Tags: python, unique, disk-based

Suppose I have very huge text file, with lines of different arbitrary lengths. I want to remove duplicate lines, how do I do this in python? How to write disk-based code, I don't understand.
Can not use bash or power shell command

There are many ways to do this by loading into RAM, but I don't understand how to do this with little to no use of RAM.

Comment: Can you use `os.system('sort -u -o outfile infile')`? You can add [memory constraints](https://ss64.com/bash/sort.html) if you really need to, though it requires a system where `sort` is available. If that's not an option, it would be trivial to add a bit of logic to eliminate dups with most any [sorting algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-algorithms/).

Answer (score 1):

I would use a shell command for it, leveraging the subprocess module. But if you can't use bash/shell, then you can read a file line-by-line, which keeps RAM consumption at a minimum, and check the hash of each new line. If the hash is new, then you write the line immediately on the output file.

A proof-of-concept implementation would be:

```
hash_set = set()
with open('input.txt', 'r') as input_file:
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as output_file:
        for line in input_file:
            h = hash(line)
            if h not in hash_set:
                hash_set.add(h)
                output_file.write(line)
```

As pointed out by @Guy , this method is not free from hash collisions. For short text, that shouldn't be a problem.
However, to mitigate this, you could use two distinct hashing functions like in the following example.

```
from hashlib import md5

hash_set = set()
with open('input.txt', 'r') as input_file:
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as output_file:
        for line in input_file:
            h = (md5(line.encode()).digest(), hash(line)) #two hashes
            if h not in hash_set:
                hash_set.add(h)
                output_file.write(line)
```

Comment: For a "very huge text file" my mind assumes GB at the least, which is at least millions of records. By "do this with little to no use of RAM" I assume MB at *most*. Both of those are subjective, since OP didn't give us any useful hard numbers, but the two might come into conflict, even with hashed lines. Should work if it meets the resource limits, though.

Comment: There is the (remote) possibility of hash collision, different lines might provide the same hash, in a huge file the chances of this happening increase (that's why I deleted my answer).

Comment: Sure, very rarely, one could use two different hashing functions for this. Any given line can be hashed with both functions and the result can be added to the set as a tuple. That's the first solution that comes to mind.